# Translate label of report's row-level formula field

Tags: reporting, translation, report-formula

How to translate the label of a  Row-Level Formula Column in a report?
Nothing about this in Translation Workbench.

Thank You

Comment: I dont think currently this feature is available (https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhFsUAJ/translation-function-for-bucket-fields-and-formula-fields-in-report)